# How to Print Both Text and image in java "Share Simple code for beginners"

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a invoice generation/bill printing system for a industry.

I need a code which print the text as well as the image logo of company.

Here I'm giving a code of JFrame I have created and I need a print code which print both the text and images by fetching data from SQL 2008 server as backend.

```
here its is a code of netbeans frame 
here i need action implementation on Print Button below:

plz help me soon providing a appropriate way to print text and image.


package invoice2;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;



/**
 *
 * @author Admin Param
 */
public class generate extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form generate
     */
    public generate() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        t9 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        d1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        logo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        print = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Generate Bill/Print Invoice");
        setToolTipText("");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(jSeparator1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, -18, 490, 20));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("No. Of Item :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(35, 20, 90, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Price of Item :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(35, 60, 90, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText(" Tex :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 280, -1, 30));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Invoice No :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(41, 90, 80, 21));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText(" Billing Address :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 130, -1, 21));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("  Sub Total :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 240, 80, 30));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText(" Total  :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 330, -1, -1));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("  Date :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 210, -1, -1));

        t7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 320, 140, 30));

        t1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 10, 140, 30));

        t2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 50, 140, 30));

        t3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 90, 140, 30));

        t5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 240, 140, 30));

        t6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(t6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 280, 140, 30));

        t9.setColumns(20);
        t9.setRows(5);
        t4.setViewportView(t9);

        jPanel1.add(t4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 130, 180, 60));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Generate  Total");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 310, 150, 40));
        jPanel1.add(d1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 200, 160, 30));

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("Generate  SubTotal");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 230, 150, 40));

        jButton5.setText("image ");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 10, 100, 40));

        logo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/invoice2/big.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(logo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 70, 130, 130));

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 30, 510, 360));

        jLabel7.setText(" Tex :");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 180, -1, 21));

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Exit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 410, 120, 40));

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Save ");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 410, 120, 40));

        print.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        print.setText("Print ");
        print.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                printActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(print, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 410, 130, 40));
        getContentPane().add(jSeparator2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 18, 480, 10));

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText(" Welcome To Invoice Print/Bill Generator Software By ArtSheoran");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 0, 510, 20));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void t7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void t1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void t2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void t3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void t5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void t6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 dispose();        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=invoice;integratedSecurity=true";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into record values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        int f1=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(1,f1);

        int f2=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(2,f2);

        int f3=Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(3,f3);

        pstmt.setString(4,t9.getText());

        java.util.Date date=d1.getDate();
        String d=String.format("%1$tm-%1$td-%1$ty",date);
        pstmt.setString(5,d);

       int f4=Integer.parseInt(t5.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(6,f4);

        int f5=Integer.parseInt(t6.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(7,f5);

        int f6=Integer.parseInt(t7.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(8,f6); 
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"record saved successfully");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException | HeadlessException ob)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ob.toString());
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        int nitem=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int price=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
        int s=nitem*price;
       t5.setText(Integer.toString(s));// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void printActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


 // here need a action under print button for text and image printing.


    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=invoice;integratedSecurity=true";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into saveimage values(?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1,"mahendra");
               pstmt.setString(2,"Delhi");
               pstmt.setString(4,"123456");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        String str="";
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
       File ob=chooser.getSelectedFile();
       str=ob.getPath();
       Icon img = new ImageIcon(str);
       logo.setIcon(img);
        pstmt.setString(3, str);

              //executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this query 
               //insert data and image from specified address.
         int s = pstmt.executeUpdate();
               if(s>0) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Uploaded Sucessfully");;
               }
               else {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not uploaded a error has been occured");
               }
           }
}
           catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
                  System.out.println("Found some error : "+ex);
           }       // TODO add your handling code here:
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser d1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel logo;
    private javax.swing.JButton print;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane t4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t7;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea t9;
    // End of variables declaration

    private static class OutputPrinter implements Printable {

        public OutputPrinter(String printData) {
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
}


Plz help me soon and write appropriate guide.to implement action of printing text and image from a JInternal Frame and using SQL Server 2008.
a good answer is awaited.
```

Comment: You could take a look at [Jasper Reports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/reporting) and save yourself a lot of hassle

Answer (score 4):

You can define HTML and set it to `JTextPane`. Then print the `JTextPane`'s content.

If you need multi page printing see http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html

Comment: sorry dear your code also not working finely some exceptions there.can you plz share some more basic or simple code.in this code actuly m not getting which parameter is passed for printing.thanx for your suggestion.share more code if u having.